# Falha na criação de array

Tags: php, array, arraylist, php-5

Estou usando php 5.3 com Postgree num projeto que eu estou trabalhando.
Dessa forma eu tenho que usar o **array()** e não o **[ ]**.
Eu tenho uma tabela que preciso enviar por e-mail mas ao enviar só está vindo o ultimo registro.
Preciso enviar essa tabela por e-mail com **todas as linhas.**
Estou tentando passar os valores da variável para um array mas ele mostra todos os valores no Índice, zero conforme imagem.
Estou usando um while. Gostaria de corrigir isso sem mudar a estrutura atual que é por **while** e não por **for**.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    $c = 0;
       while ($row = pg_fetch_array($res))                          
    {
      $c++;

    $sql1 = "
    select a.aux_nomecompltaxon from jabot.testemunho t,jabot.arvoretaxon a,jabot.determinacao d
    where a.codarvtaxon = d.codarvtaxon
    and d.coddeterminacao = t.ultimadeterm
    and t.codtestemunho = '".$row['codtestemunho']."'
    ";
    $res1 = pg_exec($conn,$sql1);
    $determinacao = pg_fetch_array($res1);

    ?>
    <tr>
        <td> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="iditemguiaremessa[]" id="iditemguiaremessa" value="<?php echo $row["iditemguiaremessa"];?>" />
        </td>
    <td> 
        <?php echo $c;?>
    </td>
        <td> 
          <?php                                 
    $array = array(
    $row['codtestemunho'] ,
    );
    print_r($array);
    ?>                                    
    <input type="hidden" name="edtcodigobarra" value="<?php echo $array[0]; ?>" >

    </td>

   }
```

Comment: Sua pergunta é bem confusa e não tem nenhum escopo. Não consegui identificar qual é o problema. O que você quer fazer? Quer reassociar o `array`? Quer enviar um e-mail?

Comment: Obrigado pelo Feedback. Vou editar para deixar mais clara.

Comment: Veja se ficou melhor, @CypherPotato?

Comment: Qual é a estrutura desse `$res`? Coloca o `var_dump` dele para gente ver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cara isso aqui

`$array = array( $row['codtestemunho'] , );`

é o mesmo que isto

`$array=$row['codtestemunho']`

e como você quer enviar o array ocm todas rows o certo seria isso aqui:

`$array[]=$row['codtestemunho']`

por que a cada iteração ( loop ) vo adiciona mais um item dentro da variavel `$array`.

e no caso de você precisar enviar por email pode fazer algo assim:

`$result = implode(",",$array);`

da um `echo` no `$result` depois para você ver.